# Custom model collection, error: disabled by default for security reasons

Tags: magento-1.7

I have created a custom model with his collection but when i try to get the collection magento seys: disabled by default for security reasons.

```
$stores = Mage::getModel("training/animal")->getCollection();
```

or

```
$stores = Mage::getResourceModel("training/animal_collection");
```

Above all the code I have wrote:

```
app/code/local/Trainig/Animal/etc/config.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Training_Animal>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Training_Animal>        
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <training>
                <class>Training_Animal_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>training_animal_resource</resourceModel>
            </training>
            <training_animal_resource>
                <class>Training_Animal_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <animal>
                        <table>training_animal_entity</table>
                    </animal>
                </entities>
            </training_animal_resource>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <training_animal_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Training_Animal</module>
                    <class>Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup> 
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
                <training_write>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_write</use>
                    </connection>
                </training_write>
                <training_read>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_read</use>
                    </connection>
                </training_read>                
            </training_animal_setup>
        </resources> 
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <training>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Training_Animal</module>
                    <frontName>traininganimal</frontName>
                </args>
            </training>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Training/Animal/Model/Animal.php

```
class Training_Animal_Model_Animal extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract{
    public function _construct() {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init("training/animal");
    }
}
```

app/code/local/Training/Animal/Model/Mysql4/Animal.php

```
class Training_Animal_Model_Mysql4_Animal extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract{
    public function _construct() {
        $this->_init("training/animal", "entity_id");
    }
}
```

aap/code/local/Training/Animal/Model/Mysql4/Animal/Collection.php

```
class Training_Animal_Model_Mysql4_Animal_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract{
        public function _construct() {
            $this->_init("training/animal");
        }
    }
```

Someone know where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should write
                 Mage::getModel("training/animal")->getCollection(); as Mage::getModel("module name/module name")